# How does GCC interpret ferror definition?

Tags: c, bare-metal, ferror

I'm working with some embedded C code for an LCD display in which one of the files includes `stdio.h` and defines `fputc`, `fgetc`, and `ferror`. `fputc` calls the LCD driver code to print a character to the screen, but the other two don't actually do anything interesting.

Whenever I try to compile the project I get the following error:

> src/ST7735.c:1578:5: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'int'
> 1578 | int ferror(FILE *f){
>
> src/ST7735.c:1578:5: error: expected ')' before '(' token  1578 | int
> ferror(FILE *f){

The error goes away if I rename `ferror` to anything else. The other two functions don't create any issues. I also found that if I do rename the function but call `ferror` elsewhere in the code, the project still compiles, when I'd expect linking to fail without a definition for `ferror` anywhere else in the project.

I'm using the *arm-none-eabi* toolchain with the `-nostdlib` flag, but the project was originally created using *Keil*. I'm not sure if that is part of the explanation. I searched Google for any relevant information but couldn't find anything. Is there something special about `ferror` in GCC?

Comment: Sounds like some header may be defining `ferror` as a macro (which is unusual, but standard-compliant). Try compiling with `-E` and looking at the preprocessed line where the error was issued.

Comment: @DanBonachea that was it, much appreciated. Inside the arm-none-eabi toolchain's stdio.h is #define ferror(p) __sferror(p).

Comment: Just to follow up on my previous comment which I think is incomplete: stdio.h contains '#define ferror(p) __sferror(p)'  which itself expands to a plain old expression.

Comment: A compiler is allowed to implement *any* standard function as a macro (in addition to implementing it as a function). Your .c file should `#undef` every standard function it attempts to redefine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> … one of the files includes `stdio.h` and defines `fputc`, `fgetc`, and `ferror`.

This seems like you are trying to implement those standard library functions, as in the way a C implementation must implement those functions for its users.

An implementor of standard library functions is responsible for providing both the header, `<stdio.h>`, and the implementations of the functions and for ensuring they work together. Including somebody else’s `<stdio.h>` and writing your own definitions is not generally a good approach to this. Often somebody else’s implementation of `<stdio.h>` contains customizations for that implementation that are not appropriate for yours. It is typically better to start by writing your own `<stdio.h>` that simply declares functions as they are described in the C standard.

Failing that, there might be no need to include `<stdio.h>` in the source file where you are defining `fputc`, `fgetc`, and `ferror`. Simply remove that header and define the functions.

If you do not wish to do that, then adding `#undef ferror` after `#include <stdio.h>` might resolve the immediate problem you are having. However, it might not resolve the whole problem, because, if source files that are using your routines include this same `<stdio.h>`, they will get the `ferror` macro defined in `<stdio.h>` and will not call the `ferror` routine you define. To resolve that, you will need to provide a different `<stdio.h>`.